Why cinnamon with wayland creates 2 unix sockets?

X11 by default will create one unix socket on /tmp/.X11-unix, which named "X" + the number of the display.
But when i use cinnamon with wayland, it creates /tmp/.X11-unix/X0 AND /tmp/.X11-unix/X1.
My question is, why it uses 2 sockets ?
And extra question: whats diference between both ? Synce looks like both display 0 and 1 are the same using cinnamon with wayland.

